# How do I get a range of a specific word for ITextDocument

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem where I want to find a word in an ITextDocument, then find it's range (to make the range characterformat bold and all)

Example: I want to make the word "hello" be bold, in the string "hey, hi, hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request should be more clear, such as whether you need to bold all or not. In fact, you can match the word with regular expression:

```
string stringToTest;
string patternToMatch = @"\bhello\b";

textDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out stringToTest);
Regex regex = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToTest);
```

And get the range with [ITextDocument.GetRange(Int32, Int32) Method](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fuwp%2Fapi%2Fwindows.ui.text.itextdocument.getrange%3Ff1url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fmsdn.microsoft.com%252Fquery%252Fdev15.query%253FappId%253DDev15IDEF1%2526l%253DEN-US%2526k%253Dk(Windows.UI.Text.ITextDocument.GetRange)%253Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%252CVersion%253Dv5.0)%253Bk(DevLang-csharp)%2526rd%253Dtrue%2526f%253D255%2526MSPPError%253D-2147217396&data=02%7C01%7C%7C4cf5539151514f7e497308d643007c6f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636770066696765759&sdata=7tIhcIm%2FJSsbl94pygylcIZoOrrmVbh%2FGlMG4aA02sI%3D&reserved=0):

```
ITextRange textRange;
textRange = textDocument.GetRange(match.Index, match.Index + 5);
```

Finally set the characterFormat with:

```
textRange.CharacterFormat = textCharacterFormat;
```

Here is a demo about bold all words:

```
    private void Bold_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    //I get the document from richEditBox.Document for my test, you can get yours
    ITextDocument textDocument = richEditBox.Document;
    ITextCharacterFormat textCharacterFormat = textDocument.GetDefaultCharacterFormat();
    textCharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On;

    string stringToTest;
    string patternToMatch = @"\bhello\b";
    ITextRange textRange;

    textDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out stringToTest);
    Regex regex = new Regex(patternToMatch, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(stringToTest);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        textRange = textDocument.GetRange(match.Index, match.Index + 5);
        textRange.CharacterFormat = textCharacterFormat;
    }
   }
```